# ActionBarSherlock with dropdown navigation don't show tabs with custom view

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am using action bar navigation where user may dynamically add tabs. Navigation mode is set with:

```
  setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

I run app on a 7'tablet with android 4.0.3 so in either landscape and portrait mode I have embedded tabs until Action Bar runs out of space and switches to drop down navigation.

Before clicking view is standard for spinner and in hierarchy viewer it contains spinner
->spinnerTabContainerView$TabView->FrameLayout->textView. Here is pic:

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWvOb.jpg)

When I click it instead of showing me a list of tabs it shows me something like this:

[post click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkKz4.jpg)

Basically it shows me all tabs but not in a drop down list and without my custom view. In Hierarchy Viewer it is showed as scrollingTabContainerView->LinearLayout->and many ScrollingTabContainerView$TabView

I tried nearly everything and I have no idea what to do next.

Here are some sources:

-SherlockActionBar Theming

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

    <item name="actionBarSize">56dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">56dip</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#DABA79</item>
</style>
```

-My custom Tab view

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/action_custom_tab"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"

/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The same problem here. Any ideas?

Comment: I ended creating custom view and setting it to the action bar with setCustomView(View) method, in the end it is far less complicated than trying to customize raw action bar and You can do anything You want with your custom view. If You want sample write me an e-mail